# Trailing Off The Back Of

Tags: meaning-in-context

I don't quite understand [this phrase](http://www.tripadvisor.com/LocationPhotoDirectLink-g293918-i45901565-Ko_Samui_Surat_Thani_Province.html)

> The Rib ***trailing off the back of*** the Naga

Does it mean "The Rib trailing ***behind*** the back of the Naga"?

Answer (score 1):

Judging by the picture, I suspect that the "Rib" is name of the boat in the picture, and the "Naga" is the name of the boat that's towing it (and where the picture is being taken from).

In this context, the phrase means that the boat in question - the Rib - is *attached* to the thing it's "trailing off the back" of: namely, the Naga.

"**behind** the back of", by contrast, does not imply that the boat is attached.

Comment: So, is it poorly written?

Comment: @meatie Worth noting that 'RIB' is an acronym for Rigid Inflatable Boat - which that appears to be - see here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rigid-hulled_inflatable_boat

Comment: @Frank  Would "The Rib ***hanging*** off the back of the Naga" be better?

Comment: @meatie It doesn't look like it is attached (but my eyes aren't what they used to be) so 'The RIB following behind the Naga' would probably be more accurate, but _trailing_ can mean _following behind_. There's no question that 'Rib' should be 'RIB' meaning Rigid Inflatable Boat.

Comment: Personally I would use "from" instead of "off" in this case, but "off" can be used in this way. I don't think it's badly written, but that would depend on context and intended audience - if you don't understand it, I guess that means it could be better written.